# Restful API with Flask and MySQL database with Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, json, raspberry-pi, mariadb, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to test Restful API with Flask and MySQL database with Raspberry Pi. Found a interesting article [Tutorial](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/flask-crud-api/)  My Full Code is below,

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, make_response
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from marshmallow import fields
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemySchema
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost:3306/todo'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Model
class Todo(db.Model):
   __tablename__ = "todos"
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   title = db.Column(db.String(20))
   todo_description = db.Column(db.String(100))

   def create(self):
       db.session.add(self)
       db.session.commit()
       return self

   def __init__(self, title, todo_description):
       self.title = title
       self.todo_description = todo_description

   def __repr__(self):
       return f"{self.id}"

db.create_all()


class TodoSchema(SQLAlchemySchema):
   class Meta(SQLAlchemySchema.Meta):
       model = Todo
       sqla_session = db.session
   id = fields.Number(dump_only=True)
   title = fields.String(required=True)
   todo_description = fields.String(required=True)


@app.route('/api/v1/todo', methods=['POST'])
def create_todo():
   data = request.get_json()
   print(data)
   todo_schema = TodoSchema()
   todo = todo_schema.load(data)
   result = todo_schema.dump(todo.create())
   return make_response(jsonify({"todo": result}), 200)
  # return 'This works',200

@app.route('/api/v1/todo', methods=['GET'])
def index():
   get_todos = Todo.query.all()
   todo_schema = TodoSchema(many=True)
   todos = todo_schema.dump(get_todos)
   return make_response(jsonify({"todos": todos}))

@app.route('/api/v1/todo/<id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_todo_by_id(id):
   get_todo = Todo.query.get(id)
   todo_schema = TodoSchema()
   todo = todo_schema.dump(get_todo)
   return make_response(jsonify({"todo": todo}))
```

But when I send Rest POST request through Postman I am getting following error,

**Error:**

```
(venv) root@raspberrypi:~/password_db_test1# flask run -h 0.0.0.0
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
/root/password_db_test1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:873: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
 * Running on all addresses.
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
 * Running on http://192.168.8.182:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
{'title': 'test title', 'todo_description': 'test'}
[2021-09-19 07:58:10,883] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/v1/todo [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/password_db_test1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/root/password_db_test1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/root/password_db_test1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/root/password_db_test1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/root/password_db_test1/app.py", line 48, in create_todo
    result = todo_schema.dump(todo.create())
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'create'
192.168.8.228 - - [19/Sep/2021 07:58:10] "POST /api/v1/todo HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I have done playing with the code and change the below

***From:***

```
result = todo_schema.dump(todo.create())
```

***To:***

```
result = todo_schema.dump(todo.create())
```

Since method is `Todo`

After that I am getting,

**Error:**

```
{'title': 'test title', 'todo_description': 'test'}
[2021-09-19 08:02:29,147] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/v1/todo [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/password_db_test1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/root/password_db_test1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/root/password_db_test1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/root/password_db_test1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/root/password_db_test1/app.py", line 48, in create_todo
    result = todo_schema.dump(Todo.create())
TypeError: create() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
192.168.8.228 - - [19/Sep/2021 08:02:29] "POST /api/v1/todo HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I changed some codes due to testing and changes in `marshmallow_sqlalchemy` import `ModelSchema` to `SQLAlchemySchema` as per the [ModelSchema_Change](https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html)

My Sample JSON POST Request from Postman is below

```
{
    "title": "test title",
    "todo_description": "test"
}
```

Please help me to sort this issue, I am doing a project to encrypted user date in mariaDB for a project using Raspberry Pi which will be this be a sample.

Comment: Do you have a debugger? If so set a breakpoint right before the line with the missing `.create()` method on the `todo` instance, and inspect the instance. It isn't right. If you don't have a debugger get one. PyCharm? VS Code?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately I don't have any debugger.

Comment: I have setup a test setup in my notebook with PyCharm+Apache XAMPP on Windows 10. It having the same issue. I have added print statement before db.session.add(self) in Model and print statment is not reaching. Am I missing a input to the todo.create()